# How to zip only specific directories using maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven-assembly-plugin to create a zip file of the project when building the project. It is successful. Now what I want is to zip only specific directories in the project.

This is the code for plugin in my pom which I used previously.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make shared resources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>resource.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And the resource.xml file is as follows.

```
<assembly>
    <id>resources</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <!-- Since it bundles all the units -->
            <directory></directory>
            <outputDirectory>/project</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>pom.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>*.iml</exclude>
                <exclude>*.jar</exclude>
                <exclude>**/src/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/target/**</exclude>
                <exclude>resource.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I want to zip only some directories of the project in the maven build.

As an example I have following folder structure in the project.

```
project

   |_directories

         |_dir1
             |_ ....
         |_dir2
             |_ ....
         |_dir3
            |_ ....
         |_pom.xml
```

What I want is make zip file which only include the directories folder. When extracting my zip file that should only contain the four directories in it.

How can I achieve this?
Does the maven-assembly-plugin is enough to do this or should I create a mojo?

Comment: Have you tried naming the directories you want explicitly by using `include` tags? 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html

Comment: are you sure that the pom.xml is in `directories` not in `project`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You misused `directory` and `outputDirectory`.

`directory` is the path in your project where the files to be zipped are taken from (so it should be `directories` in your case), `outputDirectory` the folder inside the generate zip file, where the fileset is place (since you do not want the toplevel directory, it should be `/`):

```
<assembly>
    <id>resources</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <!-- Take everything inside the directories folder -->
            <directory>directories</directory>
            <!-- And place it inside the root of the zip file -->
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```